# enumerate - continued numbering with different lists

Tags: numbering, lists, enumerate

I have three separate lists of publications:

- Journal articles
- Conference papers
- Published Abstracts

I want to number them continuously - from the first Journal article to the last abstract.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You wouldn't display them a separate bibliographies? Just lists?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 4):

You can use `enumitem` package. Here is an example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
    \noindent Journal articles  
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item paper 1
        \item paper 2
    \end{enumerate}
    Conference papers
    \begin{enumerate}[resume]
        \item paper 1
        \item paper 2
    \end{enumerate}
    Published Abstracts
    \begin{enumerate}[resume]
        \item paper 1
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]